# Object falls and hits ground - which forces are involved to change its momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, collision

When an object falls and hits the ground - which forces are involved to change its momentum?

Should $m\vec{g}$ be taken into account of the forces that were involved in the change of momentum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When an object falls and hits the ground - which forces are involved to change its momentum?

Vectorial sum of all the forces acting on the object will cause the change in momentum of the object.

When the object was in free-fall, its momentum was already changing due to gravity(assuming negligible amount of air resistance) and then it hit the ground.
(Please note that if an object is at rest on the surface of earth doesn't mean there is no gravitational force on the object; it just means that **net force on the object is zero**).

So from Newton's law:

$$\text{Change in momentum} = \frac{\text{net force}}{\text{mass}}$$.

So in summary you must include all the forces acting on the object when calculating the change in momentum or acceleration .

Answer (score 1):

In Newtonian Mechanics, if a body of mass $\mathtt{m}$ is in free-fall, then gravitational force is responsible for acceleration & hence  changing its momentum. Simple, right?
The equation of motion is $$\mathtt{m}\cdot a = \mathbf{F_g} = \mathtt{m} \cdot g$$ where $a$ is the net acceleration of the body.

Things become intricate when you consider a fluid like air. Then the falling object experiences a viscous force which acts in the opposite direction of  velocity of the falling body. **The mathematics of the viscous force for an irregular object is difficult, but it becomes nessecarily easy(not so!) in the cases where the falling body is a small sphere.**
Then by Stoke's law, viscous force is given by $$\mathbf{F_v} = 6\pi \eta \mathit{r} \mathtt{v}$$ , where $\eta$ is the coefficient of viscosity, $\mathit{r}$ is the radius of the sphere-body & $\mathtt{v}$ is the velocity at the concerned moment.

Then, equation of motion is given by:
$$\mathtt{m} \cdot a = \mathbf{F_g} - \mathbf{F_v} - \mathbf{F_t} \implies \mathtt{m} \cdot a = \mathtt{m}\cdot g - \dfrac{4 \pi {\mathit{r}}^3 \rho}{3} \cdot g  - 6 \pi \eta \mathit{r} \mathtt{v}$$, where $F_t$ is the upthrust force or force of buoyancy & $\rho$ is the density of the fluid. Now, since the body is sphere, you can substitute $\mathtt{m}$ by $\frac{4\pi {\mathit{r}}^3 \sigma}{3}$ where $\sigma$ is the density of our sphere-body. Hope that helps.

**Response to the comment:**

At any time, the downward force exerted by the earth is $\mathtt{m}\cdot g$. $g$ can be considered constant unless the height $h$ initially is greater than the earth's radius $R$ ie. $h \ll R$. Variance of $g$ with height is given by $$g \approx g_0( 1 -  \frac{2h}{R} )$$. So,you can see for $$h \ll R$ , $g \approx g_0 = \text{constant}$$.

Comment: So in the $dt$ of hitting the ground, what is the $\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt} = \vec{F} = ?$

Comment: May we say that when a small mass hits the ground, then $\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt} = \vec{F} = N - mg$ ? ($N$ is the normal force)

Comment: To me, yes. For better understanding, see Alfred Centauri's answer. It greatly goes with your query.

Answer (score 1):

Model the ground as massless critically-damped vertical spring that the particle contacts at zero height.

When the particle reaches zero height, it has some KE which is dissipated by the damping mechanism.

When in contact with the spring, there are three forces acting on the particle, gravity downward and the damper and spring force upward.  The net force upward is then

$$F_z = -(mg + kz + c\dot z ) = m\ddot z$$

or

$$\ddot z + \frac{c}{m}\dot z + \frac{k}{m}z = -g$$

For the critically damped case ($c=2\sqrt{km}$), with zero initial displacement and negative initial velocity, the solution is of the form

$$z(t) = -g\tau^2_o\left(1  - e^{-\frac{t}{\tau_o}}\right) + \left(v_0 + g\tau_o\right)te^{-\frac{t}{\tau_o}},\,t \ge 0 $$

where

$$\tau_o = \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$$

See that the particle compresses the spring (while the particle's KE is converted to heat in the damping mechanism) and asymptotically approaches a rest position $z(\infty) = -g\tau^2_0$.

By letting the spring constant become arbitrarily large, $k \rightarrow \infty$, the time constant goes to zero, $\tau_o \rightarrow 0$, and the particle effectively stops upon contact with the spring while the KE is effectively instantly converted to heat by the damping mechanism.

Using this as a simple model of the particle hitting the ground, it's easy to see the forces acting over the short time the particle decelerates to zero speed.